# Solution for storage virtual coins in mobile application

Tags: android, iphone

What is the best solution for storage of virtual coins in a mobile app?
Of course I can store locally on the device only, but this has many disadvantages I think.

For online solutions, how do you handle synching the coins when there is no connectivity?

Are there some services who do these things, or should I write my own service?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your virtual coins online, I would recommend a SQL/PHP solution. It just requires setting up a SQL database on your server and a few lines of PHP. If you look for example PHP how to insert rows into the database you will find many working examples.

If there is no connectivity you will have to decide how you want to handle that. You might require that the user be online, or you might use the last known locally stored value, etc.

Comment: do u know if the large apps save the virtual coins online or local?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenKeyVal](http://openkeyval.org/) might work for you.  However, there is the risk that the service might go away.  You might also look at storing the data is iCloud.

The best solution is to have your own server as you would have the best control over the users data.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com) which provides almost exactly what you're looking for, multiple ways for users to get coins, a built-in way for users to purchase defined items, and inventory tracking for users.